# laravel reset password custom validator?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

by looking at [ResetsPasswords code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/ResetsPasswords.php) I can see that rules method is protected:

```
 protected function rules()
    {
        return [
            'token' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        ];
    }
```

what is the appropriate way in laravel of adding another custom validation into the reset password form if I cant override the rules method?

I can override the reset method but its too big and if in the future versions they will change some logic I will be in trouble as I don't want to mess too much with security features

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but you should be able to override it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Laravel has some basic auth controllers in `App\Http\Controllers\Auth;`

One of them is the `ResetPasswordController` controller, that is loading the trait.

In this class you can just overwrite the `rules()` function.

If you don't want to update the `rules()` function, you have to update the `reset()` function to modify your array. But I do not suggest this, because this function is more complex and will be changed obviously than the `rules()` function.

If you want to update the trait, you can extend it like this:

```
trait CustomResetsPasswords {
    use ResetsPasswords;

    public function rules() {
        //return my custom rules
    }
}
```

An then in the `ResetPasswordController` you use your `CustomResetsPasswords` trait.

Comment: It does have them by default, no need to generate the auth scaffolding in this case.

Comment: I got confused and somehow thought that I cant override protected method :/

Comment: It's confusing with the naming. What you mean is final ;)

Comment: The problem is that is overwritten by the traits default validation. https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordBroker.php#L140

Comment: @OzanKurt have you found a solution to that problem? Seems like overriding the rules method just validates the validation in ResetsPassword Trait but not the validation in the PasswordBroker.

Comment: Yeah, that's just how Laravel works atm. Should be removed completely in my opinion.

Comment: @markandrewkato I added an answer about how to bypass that default validation.

Comment: @OzanKurt Thanks for the reply! It seems like the validatePasswordWithDefaults method in PasswordBroker has a hardcoded validation to the password. What I did is to just replicate the reset method of the ResetsPassword trait and override the broker validator manually using closure in my controller.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I wrote on the answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

For laravel 5.8:

In the above answer, using trait with custom rules function is not enough because in laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker.php file it uses another validation method to check the length of the password.

So in order to use your custom length for password, override both rules and password broker's validation method

create a property that stores password length

```
/**
 * Minimum length required for password
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $passwordLength = '6';
```

change your constructor function in app\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController.php

```
/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');

    $this->broker()->validator(function (array $credentials)
    {
        [$password, $confirm] = [
            $credentials['password'],
            $credentials['password_confirmation'],
        ];

        return $password === $confirm && mb_strlen($password) >= $this->passwordLength;
    });
}
```

and add rules function with your custom validations

```
/**
 * Get the password reset validation rules.
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function rules()
{
    return [
        'token' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:'.$this->passwordLength,
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite the `reset` method in the `ResetsPasswords` trait. So that it adds a custom validator to the `Broker` instance and bypasses Laravel's nonsense default validation rules.

```
/**
 * Reset the given user's password.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
public function reset(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, $this->rules(), $this->validationErrorMessages());

    // These two lines below allow you to bypass the default validation.
    $broker = $this->broker();
    $broker->validate(function () { return true; });

    $response->reset(
        $this->credentials($request), function ($user, $password) {
            $this->resetPassword($user, $password);
        }
    );

    return $response == Password::PASSWORD_RESET
                ? $this->sendResetResponse($response)
                : $this->sendResetFailedResponse($request, $response);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*For Laravel 5.8 (I've not tested more recent version)*

The simplest solution is to **ovverride** the `rules function` from ResetsPasswords Traits

```
class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{

    use ResetsPasswords;

   
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    // this function is ovverride from ResetsPasswords Traits
    protected function rules()
    {
        return [
            'token' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|min:8|confirmed',
        ];
    }
}
```