# Laravel 6 Reset Password Strength

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-6, reset-password

I've not used Laravel before & am getting familiar; I'm on v6.15.1

My issue:
I can't figure out how to change the password length requirements on the 'Reset Password' form.

What I've done:

`app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php` - This works & the form's minimum password length validation error requires a length of 12

```
/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:12', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
}
```

`app/Http/Controllers/Auth/ResetPasswordController.php` - This does not work & I'm still getting the validation error ***"The password must be at least 8 characters."***

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset requests
    | and uses a simple trait to include this behavior. You're free to
    | explore this trait and override any methods you wish to tweak.
    |
    */

    use ResetsPasswords;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after resetting their password.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';


    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:12', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

}
```

Comment: have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60797182/7263394

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure why yet until I poke around in Laravel more, but apparently the reset password controller uses a 'rules' method instead of valdiation

- In `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/ResetPasswordController.php`
- I added the construct method I added the rules method & made the
  password 1) require a length of 12 & 2) additional characters, numbers etc

  ```
   <?php

   namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

   use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
   use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;

   class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
   {
       /*
       |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
       | Password Reset Controller
       |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
       |
       | This controller is responsible for handling password reset requests
       | and uses a simple trait to include this behavior. You're free to
       | explore this trait and override any methods you wish to tweak.
       |
       */

       use ResetsPasswords;

       /**
        * Where to redirect users after resetting their password.
        *
        * @var string
        */
       protected $redirectTo = '/';


       public function __construct()
       {
           $this->middleware('guest');
       }

       // this function is ovverride from ResetsPasswords Traits
       protected function rules()
       {
           return [
               'token' => 'required',
               'email' => 'required|email',
               'password' => 'required|min:12|confirmed|regex:/^.*(?=.{3,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[\d\x])(?=.*[!$#%]).*$/',
           ];
       }


   }
  ```